# Differences between window.onload = function(){ .. } / window.onload = function(){ .. }();

Tags: javascript

I'm using in a project the following code which is not working:

```
window.onload=function(){
 //code here
};
```

but if I add at the end () it works:

```
window.onload=function(){
 //code here
}();
```

**My question is, what's the difference? What does the () at the end?**

I presume that the first one doesn't work because somewhere else the "onload" has been already called killing this one.

**Would it have the same behaviour if I always use the second option ?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`()` at the end of function, calls this `function` immediately after declaration

```
window.onload=function(){
 //code ehere
}() // function is called
```

And in this case

```
window.onload=function(){
 //code here
};
```

function will be called after

```
window.onload()
```

Comment: Would () be like a document ready ? or still would be a document onload

Comment: @themazz `window.onload` will be the result of `onload` function execution. See furas's answer

Comment: @themazz read here, about `onload` global function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

Comment: @themazz you should declare `window.onload` function before page is loaded, e.g. in `<script>` tag on page

Answer (score 5):

When you have `()` after a lambda function such as that, it means you're calling the function immediately on that line.

So, for example,

```
var x=function() {
    return 5;
}();
console.log(x);
```

would log 5 in the console.  In the case of

```
window.onload=function() {
    //code here
}();
```

that function most likely *returns* another function that gets called when the page loads.

For example,

```
window.onload=function() {
    return function() {
        console.log("Hello!");
    };
}();
```

will log "Hello!" in the console when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

`function` is assigned to `onload`

```
window.onload=function(){
 //code ehere
};
```

result of `function` is assigned to `onload`

```
window.onload=function(){
 //code ehere
}();
```

Comment: just me or you copied first code block from Ilya? ;) (notice the "ehere").

Comment: did not notice that I copy code from answer and not from question :)

Answer (score 1):

With the `()` the function you define is called immediately. In that case, it better return a function to assign to window.onload.